# Restrict the number of rows displayed in DataTable on Bokeh Server

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a Bokeh application, accessed through the command prompt using `bokeh serve --show my_app`.

On one of the tabs, there is a DataTable widget displaying millions of rows, which makes the page choppy and unresponsive.

Is there any way to restrict the number of rows that are displayed in a DataTable without explicitly restricting the data source behind it?  It's important that the user is able to sort the DataTable and see the extremities of the full dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The Bokeh [CDSView](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html) is probably what you are after (see Filtering Data section)